# Using an array as a input name in cakephp form helper

Tags: forms, cakephp, input, helper

I am trying to categorise checkboxes with category|productname values. I need to use the cakephp form helper so I am somewhat clueless as to how to do that. I tried to use an array as the input name, but I am getting a lot of errors:

```
 // Current code:
 $this->Form->input(array("catname","prodname"),array(....)

 // Expected for html:
 <input name="data[formname][catname][prodname]" ... ">
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$this->Form->input('formname.catname.prodname', ...);
```

Comment: @FinnWea Which CakePHP version do you use?

Comment: I am using CakePHP v2.4

Comment: @FinnWea I just tested it with v2.4.1, and this snippet works fine here, i.e. it creates the HTML code the OP expected in the question.

Comment: Mmm, thats strange, I used $this->Form->input('test', array('name' => 'data[test][0]'); for now.

Comment: @FinnWea Hm, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but did you check the documentation of the FormHelper (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same, I just figured out that you can print arrays with helpers this way

```
// Current code:
 $this->Form->input('Model.0.object');
```

For example, if you have 10 objects related to this model, that will print the first one, same for 1, 2 etc.